# JQuery DataTable Keydown

Tags: jquery, datatable, keydown

I am having trouble capturing keydown events using JQuery DataTable. My goal is to allow users to navigate the rows of the table using the arrow keys. Therefore, I would like to catch keydown events and move the table's selected row (this is something I am keeping track of outside the datatable using a class for the selected row) when a user presses the arrow key. However, I cannot seem to catch the keydown events.

For example, the code below does not work:

```
$('#myTable tbody').keydown(function (event){...});
```

My thought is that the issue is the table does not have focus, but perhaps this is the wrong path. For example, even if I add the following, I do not catch keydown events with the above code:

```
 $('#myTable tbody').click(function(e){ $('#myTable tbody').focus();});
```

I can catch the keydown with the $(document) but this is not desirable.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Are you looking for a delegated handler like:

    `$('#myTable').on('keydown', 'input', function(ev){ ... });`

Not sure why you're trying to put the focus on the table itself, I'm guessing you want to focus on something contained within the table. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I improved my description to give a better reason for what I am trying to do. Trying to get focus on the table was the avenue I was heading down to get the table to catch keydown events, but this might be unnecessary. I merely want to allow users to navigate the rows of the table with the arrow keys (the selected row is used to populate data on a different pane).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a working solution...code could be cleaned up a bit (and there are bugs, e.g. no limit checking), but the effect is there:

http://jsfiddle.net/BLSully/Xdkea/

The 'key' is giving the table a tabindex so it becomes "focusable". It does not need to be zero, but it needs to be "something" so that the keypress events work on it

```
<table id="myTable" tabindex=0>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 5</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    var focusedRow = null;
    $('#myTable').on('keydown', function(ev){
        console.log(ev.keyCode);
        if(focusedRow == null) {
            focusedRow = $('tr:nth-child(1)', '#myTable');
        } else if(ev.keyCode === 38) {
            focusedRow.toggleClass('focused');
            focusedRow = focusedRow.prev('tr');
        } else if(ev.keyCode === 40) {
            focusedRow.toggleClass('focused');
            focusedRow = focusedRow.next('tr');
        }
        focusedRow.toggleClass('focused');
    });
    $('#myTable').focus();
});
```

Comment: The tabindex was the trick! Thank you! Also, if anyone else looks at this answer, setting the focus in the click handler seems to produce natural feeling behavior for the interface--at least, in initial testing.

Comment: I went straight to the code and skipped over this very important part of your answer: `The 'key' is giving the table a tabindex so it becomes "focusable"` (very good solution and css can remove the weird focus border, too, if needed)